# Fortran does not understand call statement

Tags: cuda, fortran

I am attempting to use PGFortran for CUDA. I installed PGFortran on my computer and linked everything up to the best of my knowledge. To get going I decided to follow a tutorial [listed here](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/easy-introduction-cuda-fortran/). When trying to compile the code:

```
module mathOps
contains
  attributes(global) subroutine saxpy(x, y, a)
    implicit none
    real :: x(:), y(:)
    real, value :: a
    integer :: i, n
    n = size(x)
    i = blockDim%x * (blockIdx%x - 1) + threadIdx%x
    if (i <= n) y(i) = y(i) + a*x(i)
  end subroutine saxpy 
end module mathOps

program testSaxpy
  use mathOps
  use cudafor
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: N = 40000
  real :: x(N), y(N), a
  real, device :: x_d(N), y_d(N)
  type(dim3) :: grid, tBlock

  tBlock = dim3(256,1,1)
  grid = dim3(ceiling(real(N)/tBlock%x),1,1)

  x = 1.0; y = 2.0; a = 2.0
  x_d = x
  y_d = y
  call saxpy<<<grid, tblock="">>>(x_d, y_d, a)
  y = y_d
  write(*,*) 'Max error: ', maxval(abs(y-4.0))
end program testSaxpy
```

I got:

```
PGF90-S-0034-Syntax error at or near identifier saxpy (main.cuf: 29)
  0 inform,   0 warnings,   1 severes, 0 fatal for testsaxpy
```

The error points to the line `call saxpy<<<grid, tblock="">>>(x_d, y_d, a)`. For some reason it apparently hates the fact that I am using `<<<` and `>>>`? Going by the tutorial those triple chevrons are meant to be there:

> The information between the triple chevrons is the execution
>   configuration, which dictates how many device threads execute the
>   kernel in parallel.

Removing these chevrons would not make any sense since they are the purpose of the program. So why does PGFortran dislike this?

As for the compilation. I have followed the tutorial by using
`pgf90 -o saxpy main.cuf`. But since that gave an error I also tried `pgf90 -Mcuda -o saxpy main.cuf`. Same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does seem to be a text error in that blog at the kernel invocation line:

```
call saxpy<<<grid, tblock="">>>(x_d, y_d, a)
```

`tblock=""` is not correct.  You'll notice elsewhere in that blog text, the kernel invocation line is given correctly as:

```
call saxpy<<<grid,tBlock>>>(x_d, y_d, a)
```

So if you change that line accordingly in your actual code, I think you'll have better results.

Comment: I believe the typo in the [blog](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/easy-introduction-cuda-fortran/) has now been fixed.